# How to mount AWS I3 instance storage devices and use from C# app in Docker

Tags: .net, linux, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I want to use I3 fast drives from C# app that runs in Docker via ECS. But I do not see `dev/nvme0n1` in the list of drives via `System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives().Select(d => d.ToString());`:

```
"/",
"/proc",
"/dev",
"/dev/pts",
"/sys",
"/sys/fs/cgroup",
"/sys/fs/cgroup/blkio",
"/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu",
"/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct",
"/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset",
"/sys/fs/cgroup/devices", -- maybe here?
"/sys/fs/cgroup/freezer",
"/sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb",
"/sys/fs/cgroup/memory",
"/sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event",
"/dev/mqueue",
"/etc/resolv.conf",
"/etc/hostname",
"/etc/hosts",
"/dev/shm",
"/proc/bus",
"/proc/fs",
"/proc/irq",
"/proc/sys",
"/proc/sysrq-trigger",
"/proc/kcore",
"/proc/latency_stats",
"/proc/timer_list",
"/proc/sched_debug",
"/proc/scsi",
"/sys/firmware"
```

I have read that the devices are not formatted and not mounted at the start. How to format and mount them *only once when the instance starts* and not when I publish new docker images? Or do so from code but check if already mounted and keep existing data?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to store Docker [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) on instance storage.

from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/kamermans/176c190670a163b1147e#file-docker_ephemeral_create-sh-L26) commands to replace `/var/lib/docker/volumes` with a link to `dev/nvme0n1`:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
service docker stop || true
DEV="dev/nvme0n1"
umount $DEV 2>/dev/null || true
mkdir /mnt/docker-volumes 2>/dev/null || rm -rf /mnt/docker-volumes/*
mkfs.ext4 $DEV
rm -rf /var/lib/docker/vfs
rm -rf /var/lib/docker/volumes
mount -t ext4 -o noatime,data=writeback,nobh,barrier=0,commit=300 $DEV /mnt/docker-volumes
mkdir /mnt/docker-volumes/vfs
ln -s /mnt/docker-volumes/vfs /var/lib/docker/vfs
mkdir /mnt/docker-volumes/volumes
ln -s /mnt/docker-volumes/volumes /var/lib/docker/volumes

service docker start
```

Then a command `VOLUME my-vol` in Dockerfile creates/uses a volume in `/mnt/docker-volumes/volumes` directory on the host.

This commands must be run on host machine via SSH once, but then AWS ECS just works and I could publish new apps from Visual Studio with a couple of clicks. Haven't found a way to [pass user data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/bootstrap_container_instance.html) from ECS Create Cluster wizard, looks like it is not supported now.